# Can you reference newly made columns in assign while creating new columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python 2.7, I have a function through which I need to create a new column and then from that new column create a 2nd new column:

```py
def read_assign(fp, col_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(fp).assign(model_id=col_name)
    df = df.assign(analytic_sol = k95(df.average_fuel_T, df.average_rod_burnup),
                   error = np.log10((df.analytic_sol - df.avg_th_cond)/df.analytic_sol))
    return df
```

Currently I am getting an error saying that it does not recognize `df.analytic_sol` as an attribute of `df`. Do I have to create a whole new variable and do my assignment a 2nd time? Is there a better way to do this?

Currently this code works but seems inefficient to me:

```py
def read_assign(fp, col_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(fp).assign(model_id=col_name)
    df = df.assign(analytic_sol = k95(df.average_fuel_T, df.average_rod_burnup))
    df = df.assign(error = np.log10((df.analytic_sol - df.avg_th_cond)/df.analytic_sol))
    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

### For `python 3.6+`

Try writing using [`lambda funcions`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda). This works because columns aren't *"assigned"* until the [`assign`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function has finished and returned.

So within the first `assign` call, `df['analytic_sol']` does not exist yet... but with `lambda`, you are essentially referening 'self' within the function, which **does** already have the column `analytic_sol`.

```
def read_assign(fp, col_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(fp).assign(model_id=col_name)
    df = df.assign(analytic_sol = k95(df.average_fuel_T, df.average_rod_burnup),
                   error = lambda x: np.log10((x['analytic_sol'] - df.avg_th_cond) / x['analytic_sol']))
    return df
```

Comment: Also sure you are using Python 3.6+, there is an example of this lambda behavior in the pandas assign documentation here (very last example at the bottom): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 so I'm unsure if this will work for my case. This is good to know for the future though. Upvoted.